# Could Postgres be causing AKS CPU spike to 100%?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, microservices, azure-aks, dapr

My AKS Cluster jumped to 100% at 7AM, at this point the cluster was not being called by anyone. At the same time there were repeated login attempts to the postgres database.
Could this be causing the cpu usage spike?

**AKS Memory Jump**
[image: AKS Memory Jump]
**Many repeated attempts to login** (These go on infinitely)
[image: Many repeated attempts to login]

I don't believe it to be a brute force attempt because the password it literally 'password' and it would have gotten it straight away?
It is probably some internal process I am running which is causing this. (Postgresql Dapr Binding or Hasura?)

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks for your time!

Comment: Why do you think it isn't someone trying to brute-force things? The user account changes which suggests it's not an application

Comment: @RichardHuxton It does change again further down to 'root_user', it is possible it just seems a bit far fetched. Are brute force bots that common? I suppose the IP does have port 5432 exposed so could be seen as an easy target

Comment: Any IP address exposed on the internet will be targetted almost as soon as it is used. If you don't have a good password on your installation, adsume it is compromised and re-install it.

Comment: So you were just juggling swords and are now missing a finger, but you don't think those are related?  Of course you have been hacked.

Comment: Wise words, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It was a random brute force search causing the outage, due to open port (its a demo project so not a big deal)